# sorting a circular permutation using swap

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics

Some simple organisms have a circular DNA molecule as a genome, where the molecule has no beginning and no end. These circular genomes can be visualized as a sequence of integers written along the perimeter of a circle.

The swap sorting of permutation is a transformation of into the identity permutation by exchanges of adjacent elements. For example, 3142 ! 1342 ! 1324 ! 1234 is a three-step swap sorting of permutation 3124.

now the question is: 
Design an algorithm for swap sorting that uses the minimum number of swaps to sort a circular permutation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting a circular permutation using swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436170/sorting-a-circular-permutation-using-swap); please do not create duplicate questions; rather, improve the original post if it doesn't get you the desired answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a decent question (which does need some work) but the previous thread is closed and pretty tainted.

Answer (score 1):

More than just simple organisms; mtDNA is circular as well.

There are a number of algorithms to solve your problem --different operations allowed to account for distance (indel events, duplication, inversions, et cetera).

The two main algorithms for this are,

- Breakpoint distance (See: M. Blanchette, G. Bourque, and D. Sankoff.
  *Genome Informatics*, chapter on Breakpoint phylogenies, pages 25–34. 
  Universal Academy Press)
- Double-Cut and Join (see: S. Yancopoulos, O. Attie, and R. Friedberg. *Efficient sorting
  of genomic permutations by translocation, inversion and block interchange*)

You may want to check out MGR and avoid implementing these algorithms yourself. [The software package](http://research.amnh.org/scicomp/scripts/download.php) I work on includes GRAPPA and MGR with many bug-fixes from months of effort.